# How can I get rid of settingwithcopywarning pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a range of columns, including column "A"
I want to add 3 new columns to it, and this method works:

```
  for sample in samples:
     df= df1.loc[df1['sample'] == sample, ]
     df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
     df["new"] = df["A"].diff()
     df["new2"] = df["new"].diff()
     df["new3"] = np.nan
```

However all of these operations give the following warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
```

What is the right way of assigning the new columns without the warning? I've had a look at [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) but I don't understand what the issue is.

Thanks

Comment: what is your code before `df["new"] = df["A"].diff()
df["new2"] = df["new"].diff()` ?

Comment: Problem of this error is get in some lines after problemic line, obviously filtering. So is necessary copy more code to question.

Comment: I agree with jezrael, these 3 lines did not trigger `SettingWithCopyWarning` code before or after it triggered it, if you are working with *jupyter* run each line in a separate cell to find out which is triggering the warning(all assignment lines i.e lines where you use `=`(assignment) operator.)

Comment: Updated to show the code before, pycharm quoted those 3 lines, so I assumed they were the problematic ones.

Comment: Use `df= df1.loc[df1['sample'] == sample, ].copy()` for avoid error.

Comment: Thanks, I should have looked at the previous lines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @jezrael. Whenever you want to duplicate/subset a dataframe, use the .copy() at the end to avoid this type of warning. To understand why this happens, I would recommend the 2nd answer by "cs95" in this post: [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)